# Pointing to a 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write code that has a pointer point to a 2-dimensional array.

My main purpose is for not just one asd array, like I would like to point 5 array each of which is 2 dimensional.

```
int asd1[2][2];
int asd2[2][2];
int *se;
se[0] = asd1;
se[1] = asd2;
```

Comment: Have you googled "pass 2d array as parameter"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `se = asd[0];`

The reason is that the symbol `asd` yields not a pointer to an int but rather a pointer to a *one-dimensional* array of ints.

@Mig's solution may be good, too.  It depends on what you want.  In my experience, it tends to work better when you treat a two-dimensional array of a basic type like *int* as though it were a one-dimensional of length *n*n.*  (This is expecially true in numerical work, where you are likely to call BLAS and LAPACK, but may be true elsewhere, as well.  You probably aren't doing numerical work here, but, well, try @Mig's and mine both, and see which you don't prefer.  Good luck.)

Answer (score 0):

If you were allocating that array dynamically, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main() {
  int i;
  int **asd;
  asd = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * SIZE);
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    asd[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
  }

  int **se;
  se = asd;
  se[0][1] = 10;
  printf("%d %d\n", se[0][1], asd[0][1]);

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    free(asd[i]);
  }
  free(asd);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** My first answer was wrong, here's what I had said:

You need a pointer to a pointer, since your array is 2-dimensional:

```
int asd[2][2];
int **se;
se = asd;
```

Now you should be able to:

```
se[0][1] = 10;
```

Comment: No. That'll not work. `asd` is `[[int, int], [int, int]]` no pointer just elements, and `se[n][m]` expects `[int*, int*, …]` pointers to 'sub'-arrays

Comment: you can't equate se = asd, that was my problem

Comment: @Mig: The question's a C++ one - whilst you could use `malloc` and `free`, it's very C-style and retro. A more idiomatic C++ way would involve using `std::vector` (i.e. not even `new` and `delete`).

Comment: as I write my multi-dimensional array is not an dynamic array

Comment: @StuartGolodetz: Ooops, forgot about the C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
int asd[2][2];
int (*se)[2] = asd;
```

This is equivalent to

```
int (*se)[2] = &asd[0];
```

because `asd` decays to a pointer to its first element in this context.

The key thing to bear in mind is that the type of `asd[0]` is `int[2]`, not `int*`, so you need a pointer to an `int[2]` (i.e. `int (*)[2]`) and not a pointer to an `int*` (i.e. `int**`).

Incidentally, you can make an `int*` point to the first element of the `asd[0]` if you like:

```
int *p = &asd[0][0]; // or just = asd[0];, because it decays to &asd[0][0];
```

but accessing the other elements of the 2D array as if it were a 1D array, e.g. `p[2]`, would be undefined behaviour.

---

As a more general point, it's often better to eschew using raw C-style arrays altogether if you can help it. You might want to investigate `std::array` or `std::vector`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int asd[2][2] = {{0,1},{2,3}};
    int (*se)[2]; // a pointer (*se) to an array (2-element array, but only you know it, not the compiler) of array-of-two-integers [2]
    se = asd;

    printf("%d %d\n%d %d\n", se[0][0], se[0][1], se[1][0], se[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

or:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int asd[2][2] = {{0,1},{2,3}};
    int (*se)[2][2]; // a pointer (*se) to a 2-element array (first [2]) of two element array (second [2]) of ints
    se = &asd;

    printf("%d %d\n%d %d\n", (*se)[0][0], (*se)[0][1], (*se)[1][0], (*se)[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```